# Save tag of Button with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

Hello everyone i have a problem with save tag of button when i click:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonSeconds:(id)sender {


if ([sender tag] == 1) {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"time"];
    [_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВЫКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_plus setEnabled:YES];
    [_minus setEnabled:YES];
    [_editButton setTag:2];
} else if ([sender tag] == 2){
    [_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"ON" forKey:@"time"];
    [_plus setEnabled:NO];
    [_minus setEnabled:NO];
    [_editButton setTag:1];
}
```

This is initialise the method

```
 if ([[standartDefaults stringForKey:@"time"]isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
    self.editButton.tag = 2;
}else{
     self.editButton.tag = 1;
}
```

If someone could say me where is my problem.Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I would question your use of tags.

Comment: I would echo that by saying I avoid the use of tags at all costs. They almost always promote holding state in the view which is something that you shouldn't really be doing.

Comment: My question is when i click button and i go at other controller and after go back in this controller button must to save in those position what i was click for example in position of tag 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting different behaviour within your `addButtonSeconds:` than within your initialization.

At initialization:

```
self.editButton.tag == 2; // when "time" is "ON"
self.editButton.tag == 1; // when "time" is not "ON"
```

In `addButtonSeconds:`:

```
self.editButton.tag == 1; // when "time" is "ON"
self.editButton.tag == 2; // when "time" is not "ON"
```

Still, I'm not sure that what you've written logically makes sense or necessitates the use of the `tag` property. Consider subclassing `UIButton` instead .. or simply use the existing `setSelected:` and `isSelected` of `UIButton`.

**Edit**: I'll just fix your code for you based on your comments.

```
- (IBAction)addButtonSeconds:(id)sender {
  [_editButton setSelected:![_editButton isSelected]];
  [_plus setEnabled:![_editButton isSelected]];
  [_minus setEnabled:![_editButton isSelected]];
  NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [standardUserDefaults setObject:@([_editButton isSelected]) forKey:@"editSelected"];
}
```

In your initialization:

```
[_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВЫКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted];
[_editButton setSelected:[[standartDefaults stringForKey:@"editSelected"] boolValue]];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer i was change with setSelected but i want to save position of image when i click for example when i go at other controller and after go back my position of button must to be saved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Your comment's question is completely different from your original question. Do you mean that you want to save the `frame.origin` of your `UIButton`?

Comment: Yes for example when i click button image of button is change and after click agin he change with first image and i need to save image of button when is changing with NSUserDefaults.